# Better logging system for entire package

Tags: python, logging, package

I have a large package (made up of 2 dozen modules) and I have them all logging to a single file.

I've been doing this by creating a Python "logging" module object, and just passing the object around to the different instances and methods.

Is there a better way to have a single logger from within multiple modules of a package?

Thanks!

----- ADDENDUM -----

Would it be useful/pythonic to create a root class with the logger object in it, and just inherit every class object from that class?

It would solve the issue for the classes, but not necessarily for stand alone methods imported from non-class modules...

Comment: I'm not sure to get it right... Do you mean you implemented your own logging system, or that you're using the stdlib's `logging` package, instanciating a single `logger` and passing it around ?

Comment: Actually...both :) I have a class loghandler that uses python's logger module to create some different logging options (path and filename checking, logging to multiple files, to the screen or not, adding date/time/additional line info to the log line, etc.)

So, "loghandler.info('log this line')" passes the line to the loghandler object, it does a bunch of mucking about, and then uses logger to actually log the modified line.

Comment: This kind of defeats the whole point of the `logging` package, which is to keep the logging configuration out of your libraries and let the application take care of it. AFAICT all of your "logging options" and "mucking about" could be defined by the application itself using Handlers and Formatters.

Comment: And no, the solution you mention in your addendum is neither pythonic - nor good design whatever the language IMHO.

Comment: @BurningKrome: I have to concur with Bruno. You're tying logging much too tightly to your app objects. The point of `logging` is to decouple logging configuration from those objects. In the case of libraries, as Bruno has mentioned, this is what allows the _app_ developer to control how the library logs. For apps, it allows you to configure all of your logging in one place _flexibly_ (e.g. higher level for a particular module), and if you design for it, often in a configuration file that is separate from your codebase. It sounds like you've not yet had the "light bulb moment" for `logging`.

Comment: @Bruno and Manganeez: Sounds like I need to read more about the logging module and start looking for the light bulb :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only need a single logger, then you might as well use the root one. Rather than passing around your logger, just get it from the logging module in each of your modules:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.debug('Heya')
```

However, the common, recommended pattern, is to instead use named loggers, replacing the second line with:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This keeps the door open to easily change your logging configuration later to direct certain logs elsewhere or change their logging level, etc.

Comment: Note: by default, loggers inherit the root logger's settings, so using the `__name__` bit doesn't require any specific changes/additions elsewhere.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to add the lines...

    "import logging" and "logger = logging.getLogger()
"
...to every module.py file however?

Comment: @BurningKrome: yes, but that's the canonical way to use `logging`. This, and keeping the logger's configuration out of your libraries to let the application define it.